# SQL 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

Что надо поставить вместо «`???`» для того, чтобы была связь 1 к многим (`Tasks`
→ `Developers`)?

```
CREATE TABLE Developers {
    DevID int,
    Surname varchar(255),
    Name varchar(255)
};
CREATE TABLE Tasks {
    TaskID int NOT NULL,
    TaskNumber int NOT NULL,
    DevID int,
    PRIMARY KEY { TaskID },
    CONSTRAINT FK_DevTask FOREIGN KEY (<???>)
    REFERENCES Developers(<???>)
};
```

Comment: Вопросы на русском стеке надо задавать на русском языке.

Comment: А еще походу это учебное задание ...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Developers {
    DevID int,
    Surname varchar(255),
    Name varchar(255)
};
CREATE TABLE Tasks {
    TaskID int NOT NULL,
    TaskNumber int NOT NULL,
    DevID int,
    PRIMARY KEY { TaskID },
    CONSTRAINT FK_DevTask FOREIGN KEY (DevId)
    REFERENCES Developers(DevId)
};
```

Или в диалекте MS-SQL/Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks {
    TaskID int NOT NULL,
    TaskNumber int NOT NULL,
    DevID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Developers(DevId)
    PRIMARY KEY { TaskID },
};
```

Comment: Спасибо! огромное